# How to transform a list of dicts into a list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
l = [{'pet': 'cat', 'price': '39.99', 'available': 'True'}, 
{'pet': 'cat', 'price': '67.99', 'available': 'True'}, 
{'pet': 'dog', 'price': '67.00', 'available': 'False'}
,....,
{'pet': 'fish', 'price': '11.28', 'available': 'True'}]
```

How can I transform the above list into? `(*)`:

```
l_2 = [('cat','39.99','True'),('cat','67.99','True'),('dog','67.00','False'),....,('fish','11.28','True')]
```

I tried to use `.items()` and `l[1]`:

```
for l in new_list:
        new_lis.append(l.items())
```

However, I was not able to extract the second element position of the list of dictionaries into a list of tuples, as `(*)`

Comment: try with `l.values()` in your loop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Option 1**
Use a `map` (short and sweet, but slow):

```
l_2 = list(map(lambda x: tuple(x.values()), l))
```

In the `lambda` function, specify that you wish to create a tuple out of the `dict` values. This can also be sped up using a vanilla function, instead of `lambda`:

```
def foo(x): 
     return tuple(x.values())

l_2 = list(map(foo, l))
```

```
print(l_2)
[
    ('39.99', 'cat', 'True'),
    ('67.99', 'cat', 'True'),
    ('67.00', 'dog', 'False'),
    ('11.28', 'fish', 'True')
]
```

---

**Option 2**
Use a list comprehension. The other answer has already provided the solution for this.

Alternatively, as a fix to your existing solution, you just need to replace `.items()` with `.values()`:

```
new_list = []
for x in l:
     new_list.append(tuple(x.values()))

print(new_list)
[
    ('39.99', 'cat', 'True'),
    ('67.99', 'cat', 'True'),
    ('67.00', 'dog', 'False'),
    ('11.28', 'fish', 'True')
]
```

*Note that in all of these solutions, there is no guaranteed order of the generated tuples.*

---

**Timings**

```
Solution 1 (improved):   100000 loops, best of 3: 2.47 µs per loop 
Solution 2:             1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.79 µs per loop
Your solution:           100000 loops, best of 3: 2.03 µs per loop
```

Comment: @J.Do Glad to help. :)

Comment: No consideration of dict ordering?

Comment: @user2357112 Congrats on 100k! And yeah, the dicts are unordered to begin with. Only way to preserve order is if they were OrderedDicts.

Comment: Might be worth at least mentioning the ordering concerns. When people want tuples, they usually want a consistent order.

Comment: I have a question. How would we achieve if we want to create tuples not from all values but from certain values for example having only [('cat', 'True'), ('cat', 'True'), ('dog', 'False'), ('fish', 'True')]

Comment: @beginner maintain a set of whitelisted values, then iterate over your records (see option 2) and add a condition to append only if the record values are in your whitelist.

Answer (score 5):

What you need is `.values()` and not `.items()` for example (using `list-comprehension`):

```
l_2 = [tuple(x.values()) for x in l]
```

output:

```
[('cat', 'True', '39.99'), ('cat', 'True', '67.99'), ('dog', 'False', '67.00'), ('fish', 'True', '11.28')]
```

Comment: I have a question. How would we achieve if we want to create tuples not from all values but from certain values for example having only [('cat', 'True'), ('cat', 'True'), ('dog', 'False'), ('fish', 'True')]

Comment: Choose what keys you want, for example: `[(x['pet'], x['available']) for x in l]`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was trying the same thing with tuple() function which was a mistake.